# Sprite doesn't move in Java 2D game

Tags: java, 2d, sprite, move

I'm currently having a problem with my 2d Java game. Everything works for me up until the very end. When I try to move the sprite, nothing happens. 
If instead of `player.setVelY(-5);` I use `player.setY(player.getY - 5);` the sprite moves, but why setVelX and setVelY don't work? : /

Here is part of my KeyInput.java

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
   int key = e.getKeyCode();

   switch(BNeeto.state){
        case MENU:
            break;
        case GAME:
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W)
                player.setVelY(-5);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S)
                player.setVelX(5);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
                player.setVelY(-5);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
                player.setVelX(5);
            break;
        case OPTIONS:
            break;
        case PAUSE:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
}
```

Player.java

```
package bneeto.entity;

import bneeto.gfx.Texture;
import bneeto.gfx.core.CoreObject;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Player extends CoreObject{

  public Player(int x, int y, int id, Texture tex){
    super(x, y, id, tex);
  }

  @Override
  public void tick() {
     x +=  velX;
     y +=  velY;
  }

  @Override
  public void render(Graphics g) {
      g.drawImage(tex.blockStone, x, y, null);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to reduce the code you provide to the part(s) that is/are relevant to your question - this way the question is way too long and it is very hard to read through all this code - work that most people wont do (and which prevents your question from getting answers)

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you never call `tick()`.

Comment: I'm surprised `tick()` does not depend on the amount of time that has passed by since the last call.

Comment: @Zhuinden If you call tick in a fixed time interval while ensuring that there is enough performance to keep this interval up, you do not need any delta-math in your ticks (and you run at a fixed fps)